# Optimizing a functions performance using a loops wall-time

Tags: javascript, optimization

I use the following function below to update and call a `drawAccel();`function that builds out an animated strip chart.

```
function messagecb(header, message) {
    if(header.type == 6) {
       // processEchoReply(message);

   } else if(header.type == 4) {
        // accel
        var accels = message.b64UnpackAccelMsg();

        for(var index = 0; index < accels.length; ++index) {
            var accel = accels[index];
            var totalClock = accelEpochAdjust(accel.clock);

            addAccelDatum(totalClock, accel.x,  accel.y, accel.z);

        }

    if ( typeof messagecb.counter == 'undefined' ) {
      messagecb.counter = 0;
    }

    ++messagecb.counter;
    if (messagecb.counter % 10 === 0) {
      drawAccel();
    }

    } else if(header.type == 3) {
       // info
       var info2 = message.b64UnpackInfo2Msg();

       displayCurrentPosition(info2.fixtime, info2.lat, info2.lon, info2.alt);
       displayMobileStatus(info2.rssi, info2.bandClass, info2.batt);

    } else if(header.type == 11) {
        btReceive(header, message);
}
```

}

I come across some intermittent performance issues in IE8 though. So I would like to 
collect the elapsed wall time running inside the update for loop, and not call the `drawAccel()` renderer unless I'm using less than 50% of the wall time.

Pseudo code example:

```
  if ((lastEnteredTime - lastExitedTime)/(currentTime - lastEnteredTime) < .5){
       drawAccel();
  } else {
   //do nothing 
  }
```

My problem is I'm not sure how I can go about getting the last entered time and the last exited time of the loop so that I can run this condition. Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear to me exactly what you're trying to do, but something like this should get you close.  `+new Date()` will give you the number of milliseconds since 1/1/1970, so making that same call at various places should be able to get you what you want

```
var start = +new Date();

for(var index = 0; index < accels.length; ++index) {
    var accel = accels[index];
    var totalClock = accelEpochAdjust(accel.clock);

    var current = +new Date();
    var timeElapsedInMs = current - start;
    //not sure the exact test you want to run here

    addAccelDatum(totalClock, accel.x,  accel.y, accel.z);
}
```

---

Edit based on your comment.  So if you always want to have a lastEntered and lastExited values, something like this might be what you want

```
var lastEntered, lastExisted = +new Date();

for(var index = 0; index < accels.length; ++index) {
    lastEntered = +new Date();

    var accel = accels[index];
    var totalClock = accelEpochAdjust(accel.clock);

    var timeElapsedInMs = current - start;
    //not sure the exact test you want to run here

    addAccelDatum(totalClock, accel.x,  accel.y, accel.z);

    lastExisted = +new Date();
}
```

And from there you can do whatever comparisons you need.

Comment: It looks like this is getting close since it provides the current time and the start time. 'var timeElapsedInMs' seems to me would be the 'lastExitedTime' in my case, and current would obviously be the current time so now I just need to know how to get the last entered time of the loop.

Comment: @Stavros_S - close indeed - my last edit should get you a bit closer.

Comment: Thanks! Will hack on it tonight and let you know how it works out.